# automatic ajax .load request with href attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a markup like this:

```
  <div href="ajax/project1.html" class="project"> 
  </div>

  <div href="ajax/project2.html" class="project">     
  </div>

  <div href="ajax/project3.html" class="project">      
  </div>
```

I need to make ajax .load request to those files in project's href attributes and place gotten html in it's .project when page is loaded.
I'm trying this

```
$( ".project" ).load($(this).attr('href'));
```

But it does not work. 
Thank you!

Comment: `href` is not a valid attribute of `div`. Maybe use `data-href`, or, better, `data-ajax-url`.

Comment: Does it make a network call?

Comment: Is your `load()` function inside `document.ready` so it wait for the DOM to be ready?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change 'href' to another attribute name like 'data-href'. href is not valid on div element;

Second of all, you have to loop on each element like this.

```
$(function () {
    $(".project").each(function () {
        $(this).load($(this).attr('data-href'));
    });
});
```